# Indexing - page ranges showing only the first page number

Tags: indexing, makeindex

Using `imakeidx`, let's imagine I have `\index{Test}` on pages 1 to 4.
The output will be :

> Test, 1--4.

How can I get this? (f. meaning following):

> Test, 1 f.

Here is my code :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.6cm}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}
\makeindex

\renewcommand*{\seename}{V.}
\renewcommand*{\alsoname}{V. aussi}

\begin{document}
\sloppy

Test \index{Test}
\newpage

Test \index{Test}
\newpage

Test \index{Test}
\newpage

Test \index{Test}
\newpage
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Test, 1ff", i.e. two f and no space? Since "f" denotes the next page and "ff" an undetermined number of following pages.

Comment: @DG' thanks for your answer. To be honest with you this is a translation from french, so we don't really care if it is "f" or "ff" :). The template I am trying to create is supposed to do "Test 1 s." with "s" for "suivant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a style file, let's call it `mystyle.ist`, which contains the configuration for the suffixes:

```
suffix_2p " s"
suffix_3p " s"
suffix_mp " s"
```

And you have to tell `\makeindex` to use that file:

```
\makeindex[options=-s mystyle]
```

Which gives you the desired result:

[image]

Comment: That's perfect thank you very much !!